# Tensorflow | ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow, scikit-learn

I am trying to do a time series prediction with Bitcoin. I loaded my data and scaled it. When I tried to fit the data. It returns this error. There are others questions regarding the same error, but it doesn't apply to me.

Code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

# Load Data

df = pd.read_csv("exampledata.csv", header=None, names=[
                 'Date', 'Close'], parse_dates=['Date'])
print(df.head())
print(df.shape)

# The testing data
test = df.shift(-4)

# Preprocessing Data

target = df.pop('Date')

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
print(scaler.fit_transform(df))

# Creating The Model

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation='relu', input_shape=(1,)))
# This is to reshape the output for LSTM
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Lambda(
    lambda x: tf.expand_dims(model.output, axis=-1)))
# I don't understand input_shape that much, I put 1 because I will give the model 1 column of input data
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='relu'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_absolute_error',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

# Training Model

model.fit(df, epochs=100)
```

And here are the errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 39, in <module>
    model.fit(df, epochs=100)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 66, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 848, in fit
    tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 580, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 627, in _call
    self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 506, in _initialize
    *args, **kwds))
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 2446, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 2777, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 2667, in _create_graph_function
    capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 981, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 441, in wrapped_fn
    return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 968, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
ValueError: in user code:

    C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:571 train_function  *
        outputs = self.distribute_strategy.run(
    C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:951 run  **
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2290 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2649 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:541 train_step  **
        self.trainable_variables)
    C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:1804 _minimize
        trainable_variables))
    C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\optimizer_v2\optimizer_v2.py:521 _aggregate_gradients
        filtered_grads_and_vars = _filter_grads(grads_and_vars)
    C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\optimizer_v2\optimizer_v2.py:1219 _filter_grads
        ([v.name for _, v in grads_and_vars],))

    ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['dense/kernel:0', 'dense/bias:0', 'lstm/lstm_cell/kernel:0', 'lstm/lstm_cell/recurrent_kernel:0', 'lstm/lstm_cell/bias:0', 'dense_1/kernel:0', 'dense_1/bias:0'].
```

Here is my data (partially) looks like (I scaled it):

```
[[0.29738429]
 [0.27614102]
 [0.39392314]
 [0.        ]
 [1.        ]
 [0.97227646]]
```

Comment: what's the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

redefine your Lambda layer in this way

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation='relu', input_shape=(1,)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.expand_dims(x, axis=-1))) # <======
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='relu'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_absolute_error')
model.summary()

model.fit(np.random.uniform(0,1, (100,1)), np.random.uniform(0,1, 100), epochs=10)
```

---

I add a full example based on your question. **we are using the value at time t to predict the value at time t+1**

```
# substitute this with your data
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':np.random.randint(0,100, 100), 
                   'Close':np.random.uniform(0,1, 100)})

len_train = int(len(df)*0.8) # train size
# split train test
X_train = df.Close.values[:len_train]
X_test = df.Close.values[len_train:]

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train.reshape(-1, 1))
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test.reshape(-1, 1))

# create target as the next day value
y_train = X_train[1:]
X_train = X_train[:-1]
y_test = X_test[1:]
X_test = X_test[:-1]


model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation='relu', input_shape=(1,)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.expand_dims(x, axis=-1)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_absolute_error')
model.summary()

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10)

pred = model.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: It worked, but then I discovered another error: `ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['dense/kernel:0', 'dense/bias:0', 'lstm/lstm_cell/kernel:0', 'lstm/lstm_cell/recurrent_kernel:0', 'lstm/lstm_cell/bias:0', 'dense_1/kernel:0', 'dense_1/bias:0']`

Comment: are you fitting in this way (I don't see the target when you fit)? model.fit(scaler.fit_transform(df), target.values, epochs=100)

Comment: Right, I have already scaled `df`, I can't add my target, because it's a Timestamp, and it's not a compatible type. Is there a way around it?

Comment: use your X_train and y_train when you fit a model. Timestamp can't be a target

Comment: What do you mean by that? I do not have `x-train` and `y_train` variables. And my `target` variable is essentially `y_train`. It's the target variable. It's the value of that variable doesn't work; it's a timestamp.

Comment: could you please indicate what is y_train in your case (which variable in your example is y_train?)

Comment: Okay, assuming that my definition of `y_train` variable is correct. It's the target label. I have a variable called `target` in my code.

Comment: ok... you simply have to do model.fit(X_train, y_train). the error 'No gradients provided...' is because you don't provide y_train when you fit the model

Comment: So, essentially: `target` ~= `y_train`. And I just need to add that to `model.fit()`. It would make sense to rename `target` to `y_train`?

Comment: the name of the variable doesn't mean anything! you have to pass a numerical y_train/target to the model. you can't pass timestamp!!!!!

Comment: I don't know how to pass a numerical target. The target label is 'Date', and that's a Timestamp value. Could I be using the wrong column as my target label?

Comment: I currently have 2 features in my data. `Date` and `Close`. I've popped the `Data` feature into the variable `target`. Before that, it has been parsed into Timestamp value. I noticed that I have done it wrong. I need to `.pop()` the `Close` feature. But either way it would still return an error. Because instead of my `target` variable containing the Timestamp error, my `df` variable would be the one to contain the Timestamp error. I think I am doing this wrong. How does this part of time-series prediction work?

Comment: yes, you do it wrong.... I'm rewriting the whole problem for you in order to predict the next close values

Comment: Thank you, I essentially want to predict the price of Bitcoin after 'n' days. But being new to this, I don't grasp all the concepts.

Comment: so what's the problem

Comment: I don't understand the "creation" of the y_train variable.

Comment: it's x at t+1... you simple shift x of one step

Comment: Okay, got it. Thanks.

Comment: On other question, how does the model know that 'Date' has been shifted. You didn't specify that's a datetime. Does it just automatically know?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214855/discussion-between-marco-cerliani-and-aidan-l).